# Querying SQLite database from file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, iphone-web-app

I am building a web app with offline database browser.
I've got a .db3 file, but can't open it directly using sql.js or html5sql.js. What kind of loader do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a cross-browser way for opening db3 files. It could be that mobile Safari has a trick up its sleeve, but I'm no expert in that area.

You can create a similar database in Mobile Safari using a so-called [Web SQL database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). You'd have to re-create your table structure and re-insert the data, but after that you can fire pretty regular SQL queries against the local database.

Note that the Web SQL specification [has been abandoned](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) on favor of a [simpler local database standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). But it works in current mobile Safari versions, which may be good enough for your needs.